# Splunk: replace _time with value from custom field in Time Period dropdown

Tags: splunk

I have some events from the past uploaded to Splunk recently, so `_time` field isn't relevant, but I have `START_TIME` field with relevant data
In Chart diagram I have the following for replacing `_time` with `START_DATA`: `index="reporter" PROJECT_NAME="pr1" | eval NewTime=strptime(START_TIME,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") | eval _time=NewTime | ...`
Now I need `Time Period` dropdown to use `START_DATE` instead of default `_time`:

```
<input type="time" token="Time Period">
  <label>Time Period</label>
  <search>
    <query>index="reporter" PROJECT_NAME="pr1" | eval NewTime=strptime(START_TIME,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") | eval _time=NewTime</query>
    <earliest>@w0</earliest>
    <latest>now</latest>
  </search>
</input>
```

..but it doesn't work: `Node <search> is not allowed here`

Answer (score 0):

Time input fields cannot perform a search.  Probably the idea is the time range defines the search rather than the other way around.  The available elements are in the documentation at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML#Shared_input_child_elements